# Firebase Crash Free User Metrics don't makes sense

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

Is there any person that can help me understand the *Firebase Crash-Free users metrics*.

How could my crash free is 97.94% if each day on the line graph i'm 99% above.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have only 100 users. 1 of them crashes on Monday (99% crash-free). Another one crashes on Tuesday (99%). Over the 7 days period your crash-free will be 98% (since 2 out of 100 crashed).

Comment: This is the correct answer, the general crash-free rate is the rate for all users within the time-frame, the daily is within that day, but the users may be different.

Also keep in mind that the crash-free users is over the total downloads and not over the users that had a session on that period.

Answer (score 1):

A friend show me this answer about that percentage metric.

> Percentage is not average of the chart. It is crash-free unique
>   users in that time range. So your users crashed on different days

.

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/80lnni/firebase_crashlytics_cant_math